# Haskell singletons : typelits package

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, template-haskell, singleton-type

I have a hard time convincing compiler that my types are correct. With regular
`Nat`s with `Zero` and `Succ` constructors it is pretty straightforward (the goal is to write `replicate` function for length-indexed lists (`Vect`)):

```
replicate' :: SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate' SZero _ = Nil
replicate' (SSucc n) a = a :> replicate' n a
```

But regular `Nat` is drastically slow.

So there is a package that mirrors GHC.TypeLits in singletons library for faster Nats.
But I can't make the above example work with it:

```
sameNat :: forall a b. (KnownNat a, KnownNat b) => SNat a -> SNat b -> Maybe (a :~: b)
sameNat x y
  | natVal (Proxy :: Proxy a) == natVal (Proxy :: Proxy b) = Just (unsafeCoerce Refl)
  | otherwise            = Nothing

replicate'' :: (KnownNat n) => SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate'' n a =
  case sameNat n (sing :: Sing 0) of
    Just Refl -> Nil
    Nothing   -> a ::> replicate'' (sPred n) a
```

This won't typecheck on last line :

```
Couldn't match type ‘n’
                     with ‘(n GHC.TypeNats.- 1) GHC.TypeNats.+ 1’
```

Comment: `n ~ (n - 1) + 1` only holds for `n` other than `0`. _You_ know that `n` is not `0` at this point, because `sameNat` returned `Nothing`, but that doesn't give the type checker any tangible evidence to work with. You'll need to work with a richer version of `sameNat` which brings back some evidence (with which you can do some theorem proving) that `n` is not `0`, instead of `Nothing`. (Or return a GADT containing a proof that `n ~ (n - 1) + 1`, à la [_Hasochism_](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/hasochism.pdf).)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `sameNat n (sing :: Sing 0)` gives you a usable `n ~ 0` proof in the case that n is zero (when you pattern match on `Just Refl`), but if n is *not* zero it just gives you `Nothing`. That doesn't tell you anything at all about `n`, so as far as the type checker is aware you can call exactly the same set of things inside the `Nothing` branch as you could without calling `sameNat` in the first place (in particular, you can't use `sPred` because that requires that `1 <= n`).

So we need to pattern match on something that *either* provides evidence that `n ~ 0` *or* provides evidence that `1 <= n`. Something like this:

```
data IsZero (n :: Nat)
  where Zero :: (0 ~ n) => IsZero n
        NonZero :: (1 <= n) => IsZero n
deriving instance Show (IsZero n)
```

Then we could write `replicate''` this way:

```
isZero :: forall n. SNat n -> IsZero n
isZero n = _

replicate'' :: SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate'' n x = case isZero n
                    of Zero -> Nil
                       NonZero -> x ::> replicate'' (sPred n) x
```

Of course that's just moved the problem to implementing the `isZero` function, which hasn't really bought us anything, but I'm going to stick with it because it's handy to have this as the basis of any *other* inductive definitions you want to make using `Nat`.

So, implementing `isZero`. We could handle the zero case with `sameNat` of course, but that doesn't help the non-zero case. The singletons package also provides `Data.Singletons.Decide`, which gives you a way of getting a proof of equality **or inequality** of types based on their singletons. So we can do this:

```
isZero :: forall n. SNat n -> IsZero n
isZero n = case n %~ (SNat @0)
             of Proved Refl -> Zero
                Disproved nonsense -> NonZero
```

Sadly this doesn't work either! The `Proved` case is fine (and the same as `sameNat` giving us `Just Refl`, basically). But the "proof of inequality" comes in the form of `nonsense` being bound to a function of type `(n :~: 0) -> Void`, and if we assume totality (without shenanigans) then the existence of such a function "proves" that we can't construct a `n :~: 0` value, which proves that `n` definitely isn't `0`. But this is just too far from a proof that `1 <= n`; *we* can see that if `n` isn't 0 then it must be at least 1, from the properties of natural numbers, but GHC doesn't know this.

Another way to go would be to use singleton's `Ord` support and pattern match on `SNat @1 :%<= n`:

```
isZero :: forall n. SNat n -> IsZero n
isZero n = case (SNat @1) %:<= n
             of STrue -> NonZero
                SFalse -> Zero
```

But that doesn't work either, because the `STrue` and `SFalse` are just singletons for type level `True` and `False`, disconnected from the original comparison. We don't get a proof that `0 ~ n` **or** `1 <= n` from either side of this (and similarly can't get it to work by comparing with `SNat @0` either). This is type-checker boolean blindness, basically.

Ultimately I was never able to satisfactorily solve this in my code. As far as I can tell we're missing a primitive; we either need to be able to compare singletons in a way that gives us `<` or `<=` constraints on the corresponding types, or we need a switch on whether a `Nat` is zero or nonzero.

So I cheated:

```
isZero :: forall n. SNat n -> IsZero n
isZero n = case n %~ (SNat @0)
             of Proved Refl -> Zero
                Disproved _ -> unsafeCoerce (NonZero @1)
```

Since `NonZero` only contains evidence that `n` is 1 or more, but not any other information about `n`, you can just unsafely coerce a proof that 1 is 1 or more.

Here's a full working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds
           , GADTs
           , KindSignatures
           , ScopedTypeVariables
           , StandaloneDeriving
           , TypeApplications
           , TypeOperators
  #-}

import GHC.TypeLits ( type (<=), type (-) )
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits ( Sing (SNat), SNat, Nat )
import Data.Singletons.Prelude.Enum ( sPred )
import Data.Singletons.Decide ( SDecide ((%~))
                              , Decision (Proved, Disproved)
                              , (:~:) (Refl)
                              )
import Unsafe.Coerce ( unsafeCoerce )

data IsZero (n :: Nat)
  where Zero :: (0 ~ n) => IsZero n
        NonZero :: (1 <= n) => IsZero n
deriving instance Show (IsZero n)

isZero :: forall n. SNat n -> IsZero n
isZero n = case n %~ (SNat @0)
             of Proved Refl -> Zero
                Disproved _ -> unsafeCoerce (NonZero @1)


data Vect (n :: Nat) a
  where Nil :: Vect 0 a
        (::>) :: a -> Vect (n - 1) a -> Vect n a
deriving instance Show a => Show (Vect n a)

replicate'' :: SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate'' n x = case isZero n
                    of Zero -> Nil
                       NonZero -> x ::> replicate'' (sPred n) x

head'' :: (1 <= n) => Vect n a -> a
head'' (x ::> _) = x

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn
     . (:[])
     . head''
     $ replicate''
         (SNat @1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000)
         '\x1f60e'
```

Note that unlike K. A. Buhr's suggested approach using `unsafeCoerce`, here the code for replicate is actually using the type checker to verify that it constructs a `Vect n a` in accordance to the `SNat n` provided, whereas their suggestion requires you to trust that the code does this (the actual meat of the work is done by `iterate` counting on `Int`) and only makes sure that the *callers* use the `SNat n` and the `Vect n a` consistently. The only bit of code you have to just trust (unchecked by the compiler) is that a `Refuted _ :: Decision (n :~: 0)` really does imply `1 <= n`, inside `isZero` (which you can reuse to write lots of other functions that need to switch on whether a `SNat` is zero or not).

As you try to implement more functionality with your `Vect`, you'll find that a lot of "obvious" things GHC doesn't know about the properties of `Nat` are quite painful. `Data.Constraint.Nat` from the `constraints` package has a lot of useful proofs you can use (for example, if you try to implement `drop :: (k <= n) => SNat k -> Vect n a -> Vect (n - k) a`, you'll probably end up needing `leTrans` so that when you know that `1 <= k` then also `1 <= n` and you can actually pattern match to strip off another element). Avoiding this kind of hasochism is where K. A. Buhr's approach can be a great help, if you want to just implement your operation with code you trust and unsafeCoerce the types to line up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the exact approach you're taking can't work the way you want.  `sameNat` is evaluated at run-time, so its "decision" isn't available to the type checker, which therefore can't perform any type inference based on differentiating between the two branches of the case construct.

You might be interested in my answer to
[How to deconstruct an SNat (singletons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45905744/how-to-deconstruct-an-snat-singletons),
regarding a similar question, which provides an implementation that avoids `unsafeCoerce` entirely through the use of type classes.  However, as @Ben has pointed out in the comments, because of this use of type classes, the compiler has to follow a chain of `n` instance definitions whenever you define a vector of size `n` (and the compiled code may explicitly include a structure of `n` nested instance dictionaries) making this impractical for real code.  For example, a million element vector is likely to cause the *compiler* to run for too long and/or use too much memory to be acceptable.

For real code, I would suggest doing the type check manually (i.e., verifying that the code, as written, is type safe) and
forcing it with `unsafeCoerce`:

```
replicate1 :: (KnownNat n) => SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate1 n a =
  unsafeCoerce (iterate (unsafeCoerce . (a ::>)) Nil
                !! fromInteger (fromSing n))
```

Obviously, this definition misses the point of dependent typing for this particular definition, but the hope is that you can build up a set of trusted (manually type-checked) primitives and then build non-trivial algorithms on top of them that can benefit from more rigorous type-checking.

Note that in this particular case, you don't even really need the `n` parameter, so you can write:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

replicate2 :: forall a n . (KnownNat n) => a -> Vect n a
replicate2 a =
  unsafeCoerce (iterate (unsafeCoerce . (a ::>)) Nil
        !! fromInteger (fromSing (SNat :: SNat n)))
```

Anyway, a full working example is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs               #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators       #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts    #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.Prelude
import Data.Singletons.TypeLits
import Unsafe.Coerce

infixr 5 ::>
data Vect (n :: Nat) a where
  Nil :: Vect 0 a
  (::>) :: a -> Vect (n :- 1) a -> Vect n a

instance (Show a) => Show (Vect n a) where
  showsPrec _ Nil = showString "Nil"
  showsPrec d (x ::> xs) = showParen (d > prec) $
showsPrec (prec+1) x . showString " ::> " . showsPrec prec xs
where prec=5

replicate1 :: (KnownNat n) => SNat n -> a -> Vect n a
replicate1 n a =
  unsafeCoerce (iterate (unsafeCoerce . (a ::>)) Nil
        !! fromInteger (fromSing n))

replicate2 :: forall a n . (KnownNat n) => a -> Vect n a
replicate2 a =
  unsafeCoerce (iterate (unsafeCoerce . (a ::>)) Nil
        !! fromInteger (fromSing (SNat :: SNat n)))

head' :: Vect (n :+ 1) a -> a
head' (x ::> _) = x

tail' :: ((n :+ 1) :- 1) ~ n => Vect (n :+ 1) a -> Vect n a
tail' (_ ::> v) = v

main = do print (replicate2 False   :: Vect 0 Bool)
          print (replicate2 "Three" :: Vect 3 String)
          print (head' (tail' (replicate2 "1M" :: Vect 1000000 String)))

          print (replicate1 (SNat :: SNat 0) False   :: Vect 0 Bool)
          print (replicate1 (SNat :: SNat 3) "Three" :: Vect 3 String)
          print (head' (tail' (replicate1 (SNat :: SNat 1000000) "1M" :: Vect 1000000 String)))
```

Comment: I don't believe this is true: "If you type-check a 1000000-element `replicate''` call, the type-checker must explicitly run a million type checks for each link of the `::>` chain". The code of `replicate''` itself is polymorphic in `n`; the type checker processes it once without any assumptions about what `n` is. And then the call is simply checked to unify with the polymorphic type of `replicate''`, which only requires that the `SNat n` and the `Vect n a` use the same n. You seem to be implying that it has to unroll the recursion at compile time and check each call with a concrete `n`?

Comment: Well, since we don't have a working example of `replicate''`, it's hard to know for sure.  I do know that my typeclass-based `replicateV` solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46495696/7203016 runs an iteration at compile time because I tested it with a 10000-element vector, and compilation required `-freduction-depth=0` and involved a noticeable delay.

Comment: Ah, but that's quite different. If your recursion is based on recursive type class instances, then when it tries to satisfy the `VC 1000000` constraint it finds `instance VC (n :- 1) a => VC n a`, and so has to check whether it can satisfy `VC (1000000 :- 1)` before it can use it, and so on. A replicate definition that applies to *all* `n :: Nat` doesn't have that behavior at all.

Comment: I have a working version of replicate for a TypeLit-based Vec, so I'll post an answer when I get to a computer. I'm pretty sure the type checking time isn't linear in the size of my vectors...

Comment: Maybe the type class solution even has to generate a million-element chain of nested dictionaries? Each of which containing a version of `replicateV` that calls the next one in the chain, so if that's the case it effectively *does* unroll the recursion? Not too sure on that point.

Comment: @Ben So based on both of your answers we can conclude that there is, unfortunately, no 'pretty' way of writing dependent code even with the help of singletons and all released haskell extensions. Usage of coercion is inevitable. The  only thing we can do is to defer the coersion to simple prove functions that are the building blocks of more complex proofs and are guaranteed to be correct by our will :). This may be off-topic but do you have any experience with Idris ? More precise : can Idris be used to write realtime performant applications ? I feel pessimistic about this question though .

Comment: I've updated my answer, since I think @Ben must be right that the problem (long compilation) was specific to use of type classes and not a fundamental part of performing type checking inductively on `Nat`s.

Comment: @russoulmc There are some other packages that provide an expanded set of basic operations working with TypeLit Nats, so you could decide to trust one of them (which is after all what you're doing with singletons and indeed GHC itself). Then you wouldn't have to write the coerce yourself. :)   Idris looks very interesting, but I haven't done more than play with it a little, not built even a toy project with it.